# first data row skipped in import

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

I'm using a XML format file to import a CSV file, and the first data row is getting skipped. I can't figure out why.

**Format file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\n' />
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="COLUMN1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="COLUMN2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

**CSV**

```
COLUMN1,COLUMN2
"ABC","ABC123456"
"TNT","TNT123456"
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\sample.csv',
FORMATFILE='C:\sample.xml',
FIRSTROW = 2) AS a
```

**Result**

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2
------- ----------
"TNT    TNT123456"

(1 row(s) affected)
```

If `FIRSTROW` is changed to `1`, the result becomes:

```
COLUMN1                COLUMN2
---------------------  ----------
COLUMN1,COLUMN2  "ABC  ABC123456" 
"TNT                   TNT123456"
```

If the header row is removed from the CSV and `FIRSTROW` is changed to `1`, the result returns as expected:

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2
------- ----------
"ABC    ABC123456" 
"TNT    TNT123456"
```

Since this is an automated report that is delivered with headers, are there any other options to remedy this?

Comment: Okay, so he's a little terse but unless I'm being incredibly stupid (and I know little of SQL Server's internals so it's possible) I have no idea why this is being downvoted so much. It's a valid question with more than enough information to test and reproduce the problem. (We even agree on the tags which is highly unusual)

Comment: Holy unnecessary down-vote brigade

Comment: @AaronBertrand Apparently I didn't use enough words.

Comment: You should add some fluff to make your question more wordlyish.

Comment: While unintuitive, what happens when you say `FIRSTROW = 1`? Do you get two rows imported, or one, or three, or an error? Also are you sure the header row has the same row terminator?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Updated with result.

Comment: This seems like a delimiter issue - I bet your header row doesn't have a proper `\n`. Also the first column and last column in any row would keep the leading and trailing `"`, respectively.

Comment: Also try rowterminator = `'"\n'` - not sure off the top of my head how to deal with the leading `"`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Indeed it is. Any workarounds if the file will be delivered with headers?

Comment: Parse it first. C# is easy.

Comment: Yell at the person who sent you the file :-)?

Comment: @Ben The software is quite sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. I suspect there isn't a valid `\n` on the first line. Otherwise SQL Server wouldn't munge the first two rows when you change to `FIRSTROW = 1`.
2. Using `","` as the column delimiter works great for all of the columns except the first and the last column. This leaves a leading `"` on the first column, and a trailing `"` on the last column. You can deal with the latter by changing your `ROWTERMINATOR` to `"\n`, but that will only work if you can also add a trailing `"` to the header row (during the process of ensuring that there is a valid `\n` there). At that point you may as well make sure that the header row matches the data rows in all aspects, so:

   ```
   "COLUMN1","COLUMN2"
   -------------------^ this character has to be \n
   ```

In all honesty, I think you could spend a week fighting with all of these nitty-gritty `BCP` and `BULK INSERT` issues, and still not have a perfect solution that doesn't require post-op actions (such as trimming leading/trailing `"` characters from certain columns). My recommendation: spend 20 minutes and write a parser in C# that will automatically correct these files - removing the header row, ensuring the right delimiters are in place, removing all the stupid `"`, etc. before SQL Server ever sees the file. Cleaning the file up will be a lot less hassle than the hoops you're jumping through now. I'm sure there are solutions to this but IIRC you've been wrestling with it for quite some time...

Answer (score 2):

The terminator of the first field should be ',' only, not '","'.

Replace with the following line, it's gonna work:

```
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
```

Here's what happens with your original file format...

The first columns is terminating with : ","... That means, SQL server parses the first line, then reads the seconds line and get the first field:

```
COLUMN1,COLUMN2  "ABC
```

The it continues to read and get the second field (remember, we are still on the second line of the file) :

```
ABC123456"
```

It now has the first row...

It then reads the next row:

```
"TNT                   TNT123456"
```

So when you skip first row, it indeeds skips the first row because your first line is not using quotes...

Hope that helps..

Comment: If you do this you'll be left with everything being quoted; the issue as determined by Aaron is that there isn't a newline character in the first _row_.

Comment: While this may work, I don't want to apply a `REPLACE` for each column (there's 32 of them).

Comment: FreshPrinceOfSO, did you read my edited answer? I suggest you put your "header" column names quoted..

Comment: @Baral If you're suggesting to do some sort of parsing to the actual data file, that is not an option since this is an *automated* delivery.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I understand. No miracle solution here then.. Do what Aaron suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Also, please check the character encoding of the .CSV file. It may be UTF-8 with a three-byte signature.
The bcp.exe does not seem to understand this format. Make sure your file is saved in signle-byte ASCII format. You may also try to specify the UTF-8 codepage parameter ( -C 65001 ), but AFAIR it does not work on some older SQL server versions.

Edit:
When importing as .csv file with a UTF-8 signature, I have observed this same problem: the first data row (the one with the signature) gets skipped.

Comment: Hi Stanislav - Welcom to Stack Exchange. Ideally, your answers should be complete, fully written and self contained. I know you can't add a comment yet, which might have been more appropriate for this remark, but for answers, complete sentences, without text-speak and abbreviations are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\""/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\",\"" />
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\"\r\n"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="COLUMN1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="COLUMN2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

The BCP format file provided here will be helpful to skip the first field that essentially can ignore the beginning " on COLUMN1 value. The FIELD1 on the record is terminated by a Single Double quote and will be skipped. The Field2 is terminated by a Double quote followed by a Comma followed by Double quote \",\"(Back slashes here are for escaping the double quote character). The Field3 is terminated by a Double quote followed by a CR(Carriage Return) followed by LF(lineFeed) which is \"\r\n.

The system reads the first field up till the double quote and skips it, reads the second field up till \",\" and assigns it to COLUMN1, reads the third field up till \"\r\n and assigns to COLUMN2 and moves on the next record and so on. Basically this should work cleanly for your CSV file feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Put in a `false` Field `"0"` in the XML format file, but do not map any additional columns.

```
<FIELD ID="0" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"' />
```

This worked for me using the following query :

```
SELECT  * FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\sample.txt', FIRSTROW = 0,
   FORMATFILE = 'C:\sample.xml' ) AS a;
```

Comment: Didn't know this way of removing first " in a line!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, the header of CSV data need to have double quotes as well (even you try to skip the first line when you BCP or Bulk insert, this is unbelievable) or you simply remove the header (first line of your CSV file):

"COLUMN1","COLUMN2"
"ABC","ABC123456"
"TNT","TNT123456"